# R - dataframe - every x rows new number in other column

Tags: r, dataframe

my question is:

I have a matrix of 200.000 rows and 3 different columns (productID, week, order).
I want to put the productID (starting with 1) in the product column and create 26 rows for each ID. Than I want to put 1-26 in the week column for every ID.

I know it's not that hard, but I keep making mistakes.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi @Carlos! Please, share part of your data (use `dput(head(your_matrix, 10))`) and your expected result, otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you look for something like this:

```
tibble(productID = 1:4, week = 5:8, order = "Test") %>% 
 tidyr::complete(week = 1:26, productID = 1:4, fill = list(order = NA_character_))

# A tibble: 104 x 3
    week productID order
   <int>     <int> <chr>
 1     1         1 NA   
 2     1         2 NA   
 3     1         3 NA   
 4     1         4 NA   
 5     2         1 NA   
 6     2         2 NA   
 7     2         3 NA   
 8     2         4 NA   
 9     3         1 NA   
10     3         2 NA   
# ... with 94 more rows
```